# after starting eclipse my phone (htc desire) disconnects form my pc

Tags: android, eclipse, synchronization, htc-android

My phone(htc desire) loses connection with HTC Sync, version: 2.0.33 on my laptop when I start eclipse galileo. I have windows 7 32 bit.

The followings are what I have done to solve this problem but with no luck:

1. unplug and replug the usb cable.
2. installed the old version of HTC sync
3. uninstalled the old version and installed the newst version of HTC sync.

I'v to log off or restart my laptop to be able to connect the phone with htc sync again but when I start eclipse the connection is lost again!!

any idea what would the problem be?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have USB debugging on? .

Comment: @Ravi Vyas. thank you for your comment. 
When I start eclipse the adb.exe(android debug bridge) is also started which is the actual reason why the connection is lost. When I kill adb.exe the connection is back again which is exactly what I want because when I am developing applications in eclipse I would like to test them directly on my phone. Any better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: By losing connection do you mean losing access to SD card? If so please read my answer :D

Comment: no I meant losing connection with the htc sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you are losing connection to the SD card then there is no issue , this is the default behavior ( well thats is what happens on my pc) . If you want to test applications on your phone just run the app and eclipse will let you chose if you want to run the app on the phone.

Comment: It seems, at least in my case, that I dont have the luxury to choose between the emulator and the phone because when the emulator or the adb.exe is running the connection between htc sync programm on my laptop and my phone is lost. so i have to kill adb.exe and close the emulator to be able to test the app on the phone.

Comment: But why do you need htc sync to run the app , Also you can modify the run configuration to make sure eclipse asks you if you want to run the app on the phone or emulator.

Comment: you are right I dont need htc sync to run the an app, i configured the run to be able to choose between the emulator and the phone, thank you for the tip. But the original problem is still unsolved. I mean why the connection between the sync and my phone is lost when the emulator or adb.exe is running?

Comment: When connected to HTC sync the phone is in MMS mode when you run eclipse the phone switches to debug mode which makes HTC Sync think the phone was disconnected. :)